# How to create a **windows worker node** in a local kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop, kind, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to deploy **IIS web server** but, I found that docker desktop's kubernetes is a single node kubernetes cluster with a linux node, so it was impossible to run that image. I tried several methods but it's not working for me. I do have **minikube** and **kind** installed on my system and I'm running **Windows server 2022 on vmware** (*it's a vm that is provided to me for hands-on practise*)

So my question is,  How to create a cluster with windows worker node so that I can deploy this IIS server image in that local cluster ?

*thank you*